# What "i" and "v" indicates in the zypper output?

Tags: opensuse, suse, zypper

I've read the zypper man page, but it doesn't explain the output. Therefore, I am asking you to explain me what "**S**" column stands for.

For example. Type:

```
zypper se -s post
```

Some of the output looks like this:

```
S | Name                                | Type       | Version               | Arch   | Repository            
--+-------------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------   
  | libgda-4_0-postgres                 | package    | 4.1.2-1.3.48          | x86_64 | SLE11SP3-SERVER       
i | libqt4-sql-postgresql               | package    | 4.6.3-5.32.1          | x86_64 | SLE11SP3-SDK-UPDATE   
v | libqt4-sql-postgresql               | package    | 4.6.3-5.29.2          | x86_64 | SLE11SP3-SDK-UPDATE   
v | libqt4-sql-postgresql               | package    | 4.6.3-5.25.4          | x86_64 | SLE11SP3-SDK
```

The questions are:

1. What "i" means? (I think it means installed)
2. What "v" means?
3. What whitespace means (I think it means not installed)

Comment: i+   means package installation initiated by user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found here: [Zypper manual](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_(plain))

> The status column can contain the following values: i - installed, v - another version installed, or  an  empty space for neither of the former cases

Comment: What does "another version installed" refer to? Does that mean that there is a different version installed other than the version available from the repository?